# Show alternative menu based on page template AND post category

Tags: categories, menus, page-template

I'm trying to display a menu based on the page template AND the post category is used.
I got it to work for the page template like this:

```
if (is_page_template('page-template-heroes.php')){ 
                        $primaryNav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'heroes', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu_class' => $menuClass, 'menu_id' => 'top-menu', 'echo' => false ) );
```

But when I try it for a page template AND category, it's not working. Must be doing something wrong.

```
if (is_page_template('page-template-heroes.php') && in_category( 'skills-heroes' ) ){ 
                        $primaryNav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'heroes', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu_class' => $menuClass, 'menu_id' => 'top-menu', 'echo' => false ) );
```

Comment: Pages don't typically have categories. Did you enabled categories for pages? Or are you using custom templates for another post type?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm trying to have a specific menu on pages with a specific page template and all post from a certain category. I didn't know about page categories. That could be another approach, thanks.

Comment: In that case you want to use `||` (or), not `&&` (and).

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much!